# Querying the record of database for almost similar matching String value

Tags: java, mysql

The scenario is that i have a bulky database of around 500,000 records having **address** and **city** field in which there is no such standard way of inserting the value so multiple users, for example  some have inserted their city value as **bangalore** and another have inserted its **city** value as **begaluru or benglore(misspelled)**

Also in case of **address**  field same user with multiple record have inserted its address values but the values are not exaclty same for example **Mountville park Thomas gate** and **Montlee park thonas gte**.

I need to fetch all those record those are having same and almost similar values(somehow missplelled) of **address** and **city**.

Is there any way to get those records with almost similar but unmatched values?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be an expensive query, but since this will hopefully be a one-time operation, you might consider looking in a [***Levenshtein distance***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) formula.

In order to avoid needing to calculate the distance for a cartesian product of your table, you could first narrow the set of cities and addresses to be compared with a quicker sanity check... such as they begin with the same letter, and have a similar length.

You could then start off by only returning records with a very small ***Levenshtein distance***, and then gradually increasing the distance until you start to get too many false positives.

[Here's an implementation directly in MySql](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552):

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT; 
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 
    -- max strlen=255 
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256); 
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0; 
    IF s1 = s2 THEN 
      RETURN 0; 
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s2_len; 
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
            IF c > c_temp THEN  
              SET c = c_temp;  
            END IF; 
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
        END WHILE; 
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN c; 
  END;
```

This function could then be used in a a helper function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_ratio( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END;
```

You could also optimize the `levenshtein` function by passing in your current max distance... if the function passes that distance, exit without calculating the exact distance.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch.  This is a tricky one.  Regardless of the method you use, you're going to end up with a very expensive query.  My recommendation is that you write an application that duplicates the data into a new table after running it through a spell checker.  You can also implement the query in Java, reading each record, spell checking the field and comparing it.

Fortunately, some spell checkers software already exists... You can have a look at [Jazy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) or [JOrtho](http://jortho.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

SOUNDEX() may be of limited use to you, however I know from experience in normalising hotel names across the world (similar problem with mistranslation issues thrown in) that a reliable solution is going to be very difficult to create.

The best option would have involved making a standard city and/or address list.  I have no idea if anything equivilant to the Postcode Address File ( http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf ) which is available in the UK is present for your locality.  This however will be of no real use for normalising your existing data.

Ultimately any option available is going to require significant human input to ensure any normalisations are not falsely matched.

**In the first instance** I would look to rely on any area codes you have available to you (Google tells me that in India this is a PIN code?).  There are most likely database(s) available which can map these codes to areas ( http://www.geopostcodes.com/india_zip_codes ) which will remove the problem of normalising broader areas (assuming their PIN code is correct)

Regarding street-level normalisation, you may have to look at SOUNDEX() or some kind of arbitary system if you wish to normalise spelling errors / differences in how people write individual street names or places.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language that you are using, for example you can **remove vowels** before comparing strings

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table and use it to aid in the search

```
 CREATE TABLE `correct_spelling` (
    correctString varchar(100) not null,
    variant       varchar(100) not null,
    primary key   (correctString)
 )
```

You would populate the table with the known variants (manually). While this sounds crazy in the short run, it may be your best solution in the long run. and it may be reusable later in life.